# Chef event handler scoping issues

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm using the chef_slack cookbook which works fine in a recipe so far. However, I'm running into what I think is a scoping issue when using it within an event handler:

```
Chef.event_handler do
  on :run_completed do
    slack_notify "TEST"
  end
end
```

I'm getting, Undefined Method slack_notify. It works perfectly fine outside the scope of that block though. I tried digging through examples and documentation but couldn't find any solid answer. Any takers?

Answer (score 3):

Event handlers don't use the recipe DSL. It's just plain Ruby code.